# How to use sed to find a path and concatenate the output with a string

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to add a string to a sed output to form the complete path, I am not sure how I can concatenate the string to the result, how should I modify the following command? Any help would be appreciated.

```
$ go env | grep GOPATH | sed 's/.*="\(.*\)"/\1/'

/Users/Paul/go

# Would like to add /bin/hello to the above path with the end result
/Users/Paul/go/bin/hello
```

Comment: Any time you're considering using grep+sed or sed+sed you should either be using a single call to sed or a single call to awk instead, depending on the operation you're trying to perform. if you [edit] your question ti include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input (the output of `go env`) and expected output then we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in a single `awk` itself. My `go env` output has `GOPATH` like `GOPATH="/root/go"` so I have taken care of `"` part here, new values will be added before last `"` by `awk`.

```
go env |  awk '/GOPATH/{gsub(/^GOPATH="|"$/,"");$0=$0 "/bin/hello";print;exit}'
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sed` you could try following here. Stop printing of lines by `-n` option of `sed` and print only matching line which has `GOPATH` in it, along with new values attached to it.

```
go env | sed -n '/GOPATH/ s|.*="\(.*\)"|\1/bin/hello|p'
```